# Is it possible to assign keys to array elements in PHP from a value column with less code?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's assume I have an array of elements, which are arrays themselves, like so:

```
$array = [
    ['foo' => 'ABC', 'bar' => 'DEF'],
    ['foo' => 'ABB', 'bar' => 'DDD'],
    ['foo' => 'BAC', 'bar' => 'EFF'],
];
```

To set the values of the `foo` field as the key of the array I could do this:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    $new_array[$element['foo']] = $element;
}
$array = $new_array;
```

The code is naturally trivial, but I've been wondering whether there's an in-built that can do the same for me.

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) + [`_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine)

Comment: array_column($array, null, 'foo'),

Comment: No need the `array_combine` it is build in the `array_column`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) can get index as well (third argument):

> mixed $index_key = NULL

So just use as:

```
array_column($array, null, 'foo');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one liner for your case,

```
$temp = array_combine(array_column($array, 'foo'), $array);
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8ac8a4a0fc51baf08d77de3c1552de714bc18b8).

[array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) — Return the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$new_array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['foo']] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, []);
```